# Cannot install Sharepoint Server 2010 on Windows 7

Tags: 2010, installation, windows-7

I have problems trying to install Sharepoint Server 2010 on a virtual machine with Windows 7.

What I did:

1) Mounted the sharepoint image file to virtual drive 
2) Copied the files from virtual drive to C:
3) Changed the file Files\Setup\config.xml, adding

```
<Setting Id="AllowWindowsClientInstall" Value="True"/>
```

as described in the microsoft tutorial

4) Ran the setup from the C: files and tried to run the prerequisites.

What I get: an error ;) The log shows:

2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Processor architecture is (9)
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Reading the following string value/name...
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Common Startup
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - from the following registry location...
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - The value is... 
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Trying to remove the startup task if there is any.
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\SharePointServerPreparationToolStartup_0FF1CE14-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.cmd
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Error: Startup task doesn't exist. This is not a continuation after a restart.
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Locating the following command line arguments file:
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - E:\PrerequisiteInstaller.Arguments.txt
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Error: This file does not exist
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Details of the current operating system: 
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Major version number of the operating system:  (6)
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Minor version number of the operating system:  (1)
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Build number of the operating system:  (0X1DB1=7601)
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Major version number of the latest Service Pack:  (1)
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Minor version number of the latest Service Pack:  (0)
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Platform ID of the operating system:  (2)
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Product suites available on the operating system:  (0X100=256)
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Product type of the operating system: VER_NT_WORKSTATION
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Product type:  (0)
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Error: This tool supports Windows Server version 6 and version 6.1
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Configuring the application's property sheet...
2012-04-17 14:53:54 - Cannot retry
2012-04-17 14:53:57 - Opening log file
2012-04-17 14:53:57 - Opened action for user
2012-04-17 14:53:57 - C:\Users\JAN-FR~1.CAR\AppData\Local\Temp\PrerequisiteInstaller.2012.04.17-14.53.54.log

Comment: Is it Windows 7 Ultimate 64 Bit? if not then i guess you wont be able to install it.

Comment: Yes, that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

A substantial number of issues regarding SharePoint 2010 installation on the Win 7 platform is related to the proper installation of the prerequisites. I would suggest looking at PowerShell or other automated installation techniques like this one - [Script to Install SharePoint 2010 on Win 7](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint/a88cad83-f595-4487-940e-f678ce47eb5f).